# Validar URL com PHP para envio para o Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Galera eu tenho esse código que faz o processa, porém queria adicionar um validador de url, eu tentei inserir

```
  if ( ( ! isset( $site ) || ! filter_var( $site, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) && !$erro ) {
        $erro = 'Envie um site válido.';
    }
```

antes do validador de campo vazio (Facebook) porém dá erro, alguém me ajuda por favor.

```
<?php
session_start();
$btnCadUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadUsuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadUsuario){
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    include_once 'header.php';
    $dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $erro = false;

    $dados_st = array_map('strip_tags', $dados_rc);
    $dados = array_map('trim', $dados_st);


        if(in_array('',$dados)){
        $erro = true ;

                $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Preencha todos os campos</div>';

        header("Location: index.php");

    }else{



        $result_usuario = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE nome='". $dados['nome'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">RG já está cadastrado </div>';
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }


    /// NOME ///

    if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
        $_SESSION['vazio_nome'] = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> Preencha!</div>'; 
    }else{
        $_SESSION['value_nome'] = $_POST['nome'];   
    }

    /// IDADE ///

    if(empty($_POST['idade'])){
        $_SESSION['vazio_idade'] = "Campo obrigatório";     
    }else{
        $_SESSION['value_idade'] = $_POST['idade'];
    }

    /// DOCUMENTO ///


    if(empty($_POST['documento'])){
        $_SESSION['vazio_documento'] = "RG é obrigatório";  
    }else{
        $_SESSION['value_documento'] = $_POST['documento'];
    }

    /// FACEBOOK ///


    if (empty($_POST['facebook'])){
        $_SESSION['vazio_facebook'] = "Campo obrigatório";  
    }

    else{
        $_SESSION['value_facebook'] = $_POST['facebook'];
    }





    //var_dump($dados);
    if(!$erro){


        $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, idade, facebook, documento,  created) VALUES (
        '" . $dados['nome'] . "',
        '" . $dados['idade'] . "',
        '" . $dados['facebook'] . "',
        '" . $dados['documento'] . "',

        NOW())";


        $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

        if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Muito bem, Boa Sorte!!!</div>';
            unset($_SESSION['value_nome']);
            unset($_SESSION['value_idade']);
            unset($_SESSION['value_documento']);
            unset($_SESSION['value_facebook']);

            header("Location: index.php");

        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro</div>';
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Explica melhor, não entendi direito, você quer validar oque no url?

Comment: Desculpa a falta de informação, eu quero validar a URL em si se é uma URL mesmo ou não, <?php
$url = 'http://com.br';
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
echo 'URL é inválida';
} else {
echo 'A URL é válida';
}
?>   dessa forma, só que no meu projeto.

Comment: ok encontrei,  você quer que o resto do codigo dó funcione se ele passar pelo url?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Estou editando a resposta pelo fato de ter entendido errado a pergunta, no seu caso você ou o usuário que tem acesso ao formulario vai inserir um url é isso?
então a resposta é HTML5 e não PHP

O seu input precisa ser assim:

```
<input type="url" name="facebook" class="form-control required" placeholder="Facebook">
```

repare que eu alterei o campo type de text para url, o proprio html vai fazer essa verificação.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90762/discussion-on-answer-by-martins-luan-validar-url-com-php-para-envio-para-o-banco), basta clicar no link caso tenham algo a acrescentar.